# hashing 1000 words using extendible hash table

Tags: java

I need to write an extendible hash table the read 1000 words from a file. It should starts with one key on the table and hash a word into 32 bitmask. I don't know how can I make words into 32 bit. The size of the bucket should be 20.
I understand the structure and what happens in extendible but i don't know how to start

Comment: You could look at Java's `String#hashCode` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function) for a real-life hash function. Or, if you want to roll your own for practice, you could start with taking just the first four bytes of the UTF-8 encoded String. Obviously that has problems (lots of collisions for shared prefixes), but makes for a good learning experience.

Comment: A hash function doesn't need to 'make [all the words] into 32 bits'. It only needs to (well, should) ensure the resulting hashes are generally well distributed (see `Object#hashCode` for the general rules of any such hash function). I recommend starting by following some EH examples / pseudo-code.

Comment: A very simple way to start is to use a hash function that always returns some constant. The rest of your code should work even if all inputs happen to hash to the same number. Then work on getting well distributed hash codes, for example by using String's hashCode() method.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: an `int` in Java is 32 bits wide, and [Object#hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) returns an integer :)

If you're starting with a relatively small bucket, you might want to consider using a technique like [linear hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) where you progressively use more of the hash until you start getting collisions. For example, you could start off using the first 8 bits of a String's hashcode. Very roughly:

```
String[] bucket = new String[20];

String thingToHash = "foo";
int thingHashCode = thingToHash.hashCode();
int bucketIndex = (byte) thingHashCode;

bucket[bucketIndex] = thingToHash;
```